# Snakefile : Including rules within for loop is not working

Tags: python, snakemake

I an currently working with snakemake framework, and I would need to iterate over a list to create rules, like this example :

```
l=[
  {"name": "one", "output": "1.txt", "shell": "touch 1.txt"},
  {"name": "two", "output": "2.txt", "shell": "touch 2.txt"}
]
for i in l:
  rule:
    name: i["name"]
    output: i["output"]
    shell: i["shell"]


rule all:
  input:
    "1.txt",
    "2.txt"
```

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 10
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job      count    min threads    max threads
-----  -------  -------------  -------------
all          1              1              1
one          1              1              1
two          1              1              1
total        3              1              1
```

But at the execution I have the following error:

```
rule two:
    output: 2.txt
    jobid: 2
    reason: Forced execution
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/7j/s10tsc1d0qv1rvl0_k76yzkm0000gn/T

Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in rule one in file /Users/grasseld/Documents/git_repos/OCEAN/GLOPO/glopo-cli/programs/workflow.smk, line 6:
Job 1  completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
1.txt
```

It seems in a for loop it always create the last element only..

If I write down directly like this example (without for loop) it's working :

```
rule one:
  output: "1.txt"
  shell: "touch 1.txt"

rule two:
  output: "2.txt"
  shell: "touch 2.txt"


rule all:
  input:
    "1.txt",
    "2.txt"
```

Why is my loop throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your loop is that you are defining multiple rules with the same name, which is not allowed in Snakemake. Specifically, in each iteration of the loop, you are defining a new rule with the same name as the previous one, which causes the rules to overwrite each other. As a result, only the last rule defined in the loop is being considered by Snakemake when constructing the DAG.

To fix this, you can give each rule a unique name based on the index of the iteration. For example:

```
l=[
  {"name": "one", "output": "1.txt", "shell": "touch 1.txt"},
  {"name": "two", "output": "2.txt", "shell": "touch 2.txt"}
]

for i, rule_config in enumerate(l):
  rule_name = f"rule_{i}"
  rule(
    name=rule_name,
    output=rule_config["output"],
    shell=rule_config["shell"]
  )

rule all:
  input:
    "1.txt",
    "2.txt"
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help ! I tried it but it seems it does not understand this part :
```
rule(
    name=rule_name,
    output=rule_config["output"],
    shell=rule_config["shell"]
  )  
```
I could not find it on the snakemake doc !

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a new name for each rule, so that is not an issue.  Indeed, if you remove the name directive you can create anonymous rules and still see the same behavior.  If you reverse the order you iterate over l and add some echos to your shells, you can see that the shell directive is overwritten.

It's not even an issue with it being in a for loop.  It seems like all anonymous rules in a snakefile share the same shell directive, which is definitely a bug.  I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2178).

As an aside, if you need different names, shells, and outputs for your rules you should probably just have separate rules.  I don't know what's to gain from taking in a struct and converting to rules but I'd be interested in your application.